# Run code every n invocations

Tags: java, multithreading

I came across a situation where I needed code to run every `n` invocations of a method.  Specifically, I was clearing out massive amounts of data and needed to hint to the VM that it should run garbage collection.  My solution was a little more condensed than this, but this class offers reuseability and ensures accurate counts.

```
public class ExecutionLimiter {
    private final AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final Runnable task;
    private final int runEvery;

    public ExecutionLimiter(Runnable task, int runEvery){
        this.task = task;
        this.runEvery = runEvery;
    }

    public boolean tryRun(){
        synchronized(ai){
            if(ai.incrementAndGet() != runEvery) return false;
            ai.set(0);
        }
        task.run();
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException{
        AtomicInteger example = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(5);
        ExecutionLimiter limiter = new ExecutionLimiter(example::incrementAndGet, 10);

        int invocations = 100;

        for(int i=0;i<invocations;i++){
            service.submit(()->{
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
                }catch(InterruptedException ignore){}
                if(limiter.tryRun())
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                            ": Successfully ran: value is " + example.get());
            });
        }

        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(invocations, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

I can't help but feel that something like this exists already in Java, but I haven't been able to find it.  The closest I've come is [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), but I don't want to hang my threads while incrementing.

A few concerns:

- Is `AtomicInteger` overkill for this class?  Would it be better to use an `int` and synchronize on a lock `Object`?
- Should I be synchronizing `AtomicInteger` to perform the `incrementAndGet`-and-`set`, or is there a better way to go about this?

The `main` is just for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         synchronized(ai){
>             if(ai.incrementAndGet() != runEvery) return false;
>             ai.set(0);
>         }
> ```

You should either use `AtomicInteger` or use `synchronized`.  Using both together is certainly overkill.

Consider

```
    private static int count = 0;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

and later

```
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (++count != runEvery) {
                return false;
            }

            count = 0;
        }
```

Then you don't need the `AtomicInteger` at all.

I prefer a descriptive name like `count` to an abbreviated type name like `ai`.  This is especially so in this case, as my natural expansion of AI is Artificial Intelligence.

You use `AtomicInteger` when you don't want to use a `synchronized` block.  Perhaps

```
        int current = ai.incrementAndGet();
        if (current % runEvery != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        int next = 0;
        do {
            if (ai.compareAndSet(current, next) {
                task.run();
                return true;
            }
            current = ai.get();
            next = current - runEvery;
        } while (next >= 0);
```

Obviously this is more complicated than the `synchronized` version.  But this is how one uses an `AtomicInteger`.

The modulus is more reliable in case of high contention that keeps `compareAndSet` from returning true.

If we aren't worried that the `count` will overflow the bounds of integer, we can get rid of the reset.  Without the reset, this makes more sense:

```
        if (ai.incrementAndGet() % runEvery != 0) {
            return false;
        }
```

That's how an `AtomicInteger` is supposed to work.  Even if two threads call this code at the same time, only one will get past the check.  Because the update happens atomically.  The problem with the original code is that there are actually two updates and you need to synchronize them.

Of course, if the range for `ai` is not constrained, then it will overflow eventually.  The `synchronized` block is more reliable in that case.  This usage fits `synchronized` better than atomic types because there's no atomic increment, compare, and reset operation.

You could also use an explicit [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) here, but you don't seem to need it.  The blocking behavior of `synchronized` better matches what you are doing.  The lock would be better if it were OK to only sometimes update (when you can get the lock) and sometimes not (when you can't get the lock).  But that's not what you are doing here.

It would be possible to create a new class with the necessary method (`countCompareReset`), but it may be simpler just to use the lock variable with the synchronization block.

Comment: Thanks for the detail! My original implementation used modulus, but I was worried about overflow, so instead of using an `int` like a good little developer, I synchronized on two operations. I always forget about the boxed classes; synchronizing on `Integer` should make things go much more smoothly! Also, `ai` is an artifact of IDE autonaming, sorry!

Comment: Tried implementing this and noticed a pretty big flaw.  `Integer` can't be declared as `final` due to operations being unboxed (assign the `Integer` to a new `Integer` resulting from an `int` operation), therefore cannot be synchronized on reliably.  Without using something with in-built methods like `AtomicInteger` or `BigInteger`, you need a `final` lock object, which is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your code!

But this code has some issues:

## exaggerated synchronization

> Is AtomicInteger overkill for this class? Would it be better to use an int and synchronize on a lock Object?

Yes.

The code that must run uninterrupted is the *increment*, the *compare* and the *reset* of the counter value. 
Therefore you need the `synchronized` block.

The use of AtomicInteger is exaggerated synchronization which may slow down your application and (in more complex situations) even cause dead locks.

So always carefully choose your *synchronization scope" as you would do with "transaction scope" when talking to a databases...

## tell, don't ask!

Your `tryRun()` method returns a `boolean` to tell the caller if the execution was successful or not. 
For what reason?

The caller cold place the "successful" indication into the task to run so that it does not need to wait for the task to finish (which makes concurrent execution kind of meaningless...).

Comment: I see your first point, but the second point mirrors the behavior of `Spliterator#tryAccept()`. I suppose I could asynchronously run the task, but that means spawning another thread unless I complicate things with an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @ndm13 there is no method `Spliterator#tryAccept()`, the only method returning abolean is `Spliterator#hasCharacteristics(int characteristics)`. Furthermore: the `Spliterator`  interface has nothing to do with concurrency.

Comment: `tryAdvance`; sorry, I'm on mobile. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer- And I don't understand how the action invocation taking longer than the inaction invocation makes concurrency "meaningless."